# What word to use when you don't want to eat more food?

Tags: word-choice

Which word to use when you don't want to eat more food even though you are not full yet, because the food is too oily and fatty.

Comment: Do you want to be polite or totally honest? The word *full* as in "*I'm full, I couldn't possibly eat any more*" will normally get you get out of these type of  situations. It's called a little white lie :) Of course, you could just say: "I'm sorry, but I'm on a diet" (that works for me).

Comment: Interested to know if there is a word, I usually say its a bit *unhealthy* or I am *on a diet* | *put off*

Comment: I think you all misunderstand the question, my bad :( Anyway, what im asking for is a word that describes the feeling that you don't want to finish a dish even when you can eat more. The reason can be because the cooker put too much oil inside (e.g. fried rice), or it's too sweet etc.

Comment: "lost my appetite"? "disgusted"?

Comment: I understood :) But you won't find a single word for: [I am not full but I don't want to eat this fatty greasy food, even If I'm still a little hungry](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g) :)

Comment: Greasy is a good word to know, thanks Mari-Lou too :D

Comment: Interestingly, in German we have the word "satt" which means "not hungry". However, neither German nor English offers a single word that means "not thirsty".

Comment: This sounds like a politeness question hidden inside of a word-choice question. There might very well be a word for not wanting to continue to eat because of the quality of food, but I'm having a hard time imagining any culture except robots where actually using the word would be acceptable to the cook. OK, maybe use it if you're king and you're also a jerk. Even king's need to be polite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept you are asking about is probably not quite expressible in English by a single adjective, but "I've **lost my appetite**" is a phrase you can use to imply that you are not eating any more not because you are full, but rather because you cannot make yourself eat any more.

My other suggestion was applicable when relating the event later (to emotionally uninvolved parties): "I was really hungry, but after the first bite I was already thoroughly **disgusted**." However, somewhat more naturally, you'd describe the food rather than yourself, as "**disgustingly** greasy" or similar.

Note that "greasy" by itself is not necessarily negative by itself: there are some dishes that are delicious only when they are greasy.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to say that the food is "too rich." Food is called rich when it has a high amount of fat content to it. This could be greasy food, food with a high dairy content, or other various things. It's hard to eat very much rich food before your stomach will get upset at the high fat content. Usually if you say that the food is delicious but far too rich, people will understand and let you set it aside, and maybe pick up a salad instead!

> **rich** *adjective**
>   2.2 (of food) containing a large amount of fat, spices, sugar, etc.
>   ‘My friend really loved it, though it was a little too rich for my tastes.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/rich)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the word *queasy*, an adjective meaning feeling nauseated or close to it:  "No, thank you, I am a bit queasy."

{American Psychological Association (APA):
queasy. (n.d.). The American Heritage® Stedman's Medical Dictionary.}

This question has a cultural component. If you are a guest in someone's home, it is most polite to say simply, "No, thank you." or "I do not care for any more." Talking about the food being unappetizing or referring to your body processes is not considerate of the host or the other diners.

Answer (score 1):

- I've **had enough** of hash browns. I am still hungry. I would like to have some brinjal steaks.
- I've had **too much** orange juice. It is irritating my throat. I am still thirsty. I would like to drink some plain water.
- I have practiced **too much** Bach today. I need to practice some Chopin.
- We have invested **too much** money in high-risk commodities. What do we do with the rest of the funds? We should invest in high-stability government bonds and stocks.